How to convert Chrome's cookie timestamp to a Delphi TDateTime?
I need to convert an integer from a Google Chrome cookie's timestamp to a Delphi TDateTime value.
For instance, this is one value extracted from an example cookie:
1765064691
The 'real' datetime of this value is 12/6/2025 8:44:51 PM, but I don't know how to get this same value in Delphi. Here is what I tried:
var d : TDateTime;
begin
  d := StrToDateTime(StrToInt('1765064691'));
end;

But I got an exception. Any ideas?

No, that's not "Chrome", it's a Unix timestamp (epoch) = seconds since 1970-01-01. Judging by your "real" time you live in timezone -0300 without saying so. Use System.DateUtils.UnixToDateTime().

In the answer to your last Q about "cookies "expiration_time"" you were told it is a "unix timestamp" in the code comment.

If that cookie comes from CEF then use the CefBaseTimeToDateTime function available in the uCEFMiscFunctions unit of the CEF4Delphi project to convert it.
TCefBaseTime is an Int64 that represents a wall clock time in UTC.
Values are not guaranteed to be monotonically non-decreasing and are subject to large amounts of skew. Time is stored internally as microseconds since the Windows epoch (1601).
